# RJAGS unable to find appropriate sampler when constraining covariance matrix

Tags: r, mcmc, rjags

I am using RJAGS to make inference on mean and covariance matrix from some data and I noticed that whenever I put a constraint in the precision matrix I receive the following error message

> Error in jags.model(file = "model.tmp", data = data) : Error in node 
>   B Unable to find appropriate sampler

Here is a minimal example where I multiply mean and precision matrix by a constant vector.
Note that the error message appears only when the precision matrix is rescaled. For some reason RJAGS is fine with rescaling the mean only.
In this simple case obviously I could have rescaled the data by A0 first, however I want to be able to do it when A0 is not known in advance. Any ideas?

```
model="model {

     for(i in 1:N){
         X[i,1:3] ~ dmnorm(An,Bn)
     }

     B ~ dwish(B0,3)

     for(i in 1:3){
         An[i]=A[i]*A0[i]
         for(j in 1:3){
             Bn[i,j]=B[i,j]*A0[i]
         }
     }

     for(i in 1:3){
         for(j in 1:3){              
             B0[i,j]=equals(i,j)*1e-3
         }
     }

     A ~ dmnorm(c(0,0,0),B0)

}"

X=matrix(rnorm(300,0,1),ncol=3)

data=list(X=X,N=nrow(X),A0=c(1,2,2));

varnames=c("A","B","S")

burn_in=100;
steps=10000;
thin=1;

fileConn=file("model.tmp")
writeLines(model,fileConn);
close(fileConn)

m=jags.model(file="model.tmp",data=data);
update(m,burn_in)
draw=jags.samples(m,steps,thin=thin,variable.names=varnames)
```